# Verbose Oracle RDBMS error log output examples?

Tags: oracle, errors, rdbms, error-log

I'm working on a project and my boss has asked that I find an actual example of the "verbose" output of an Oracle RDBMS query error. We want to see what they actually look like. I know that there are, of course, a number of different queries that can be ran against a database, so my request more pertains to error log messages that can be used to reveal information about a database's data structures.

Any information on where to find examples of such errors would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you really want but the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28278/toc.htm) is a good place to start, all 86 pages of it.

Just thinking about Oracle error codes gets me all nostalgic for those cryptic messages

- ORA-00600: internal error code  (something happened but we can't tell you)
- ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel (you, or your database or your connection are down, somewhere...)
- ORA-12154: TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified (your database does not want to talk to you)

You also may be thinking of [DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2014/14-jan/o14plsql-2045346.html) which will tell you more about errors in PL/SQL programs.  This is not the same as your question about verbose messages for SQL queries.

Comment: Okay, that's very useful (thanks), but I acknowledge my query as malformed (ha!). I was told that there are "lean" errors and "verbose" errors. The documentation you linked provides errors that I was told are the lean type, and that it's possible to generate more verbose error messages. In the example I was given, for example, the error message would provide the code and flavor text PLUS a description of why it was wrong: there are actually 50 columns in the table you're querying, or something else specific is wrong with the query you have made. In that way, it reveals info about the db.